# WPF MeasureOverride infinite available size when used in Grid column with Width="Auto"?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a `UserControl` which is supposed to be used inside a `Grid`. This `UserControl` should have a `Width` of either all the available space, or `100`, depending on a `bool`. I'm trying to accomplish this using `MeasureOverride` in my `UserControl`.

The issue that I'm running into is the following: when my `UserControl` is placed inside a `Grid` column with `Width="Auto"`, the available `Size` that I get has an `Infinite` `Width`.

I expected a `Width` of the `Grid` itself, minus any other fixed `Column` `Width`s etc.

Example code:
**Usercontrol XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="Custom UserControl content" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl codebehind:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class UserControl1
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Expand), typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

        public bool Expand
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(ExpandProperty);
            set => SetValue(ExpandProperty, value);
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            if (Expand)
            {
                //constraint.Width is infinite, creates exception
                return constraint;
            }
            return new Size(100, constraint.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main window XAML:**

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Beige" Grid.Column="0">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyControl,Path=Expand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Expand MyControl"/>
        </CheckBox>
    </Grid>
    <wpfApp1:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" x:Name="MyControl" Background="CornflowerBlue"/>
</Grid>
```

**Is there any decent way to accomplish what I want? Or perhaps I should try to approach it in a different way?**

Comment: Try setting the width of the 2nd column definition inside the main window to * instead of Auto

Comment: Makes my `UserControl` always the same width, regardless of the `Expand` property

Comment: `Width="Auto"` means that the column width should be set to the contained element's "desired" width, i.e. the width it would like to get when there is infinite space.

Comment: Since your grid width is unconstrained - it can grow to any width. So infinite width in Measure just means - take as much as you need.

Comment: @Evk why isn't it constrained to the size of the Window (or element) that the Grid is inside of? It it possible to constrain it to that?

Comment: Because grid column width is "Auto" - there is no "available space". If you need "all available space" - you have to use Width *. Auto means "size this column as largest children element in it". Anyway, for your goal I think `Measure` is not needed. You can just set `Width` to either "100" or `double.Nan` in property changed callback for `ExpandProperty`.

Comment: `Width="*"` prevents me from making the column size to it's content, from what I understand about it. As for setting the `Width` to `double.nan`, what if I want the available width for something else (for example, setting a maximum width on my `UserControl` that's either the available width or less)

Comment: But you contradict yourself. If you want to size column to it's content - then why do you want to size it to "available width" instead in your `Measure`? Measure contents of your user control and return that from `Measure`. As for `double.Nan` - that's "default" Width, unless you set it explicitly to some other value. So it will let default implementation of `Measure` to size your control to its desired width.

Comment: My eventual goal is a tab control which can be collapsed (while keeping tab headers visible), which should also be resizable by the user. I don't want the user to resize it past the maximum available size possible in the `Grid`.